# HTML audio playing issues when specific key is pressed

Tags: html

Im trying to make this audio play when a specific key is pressed and will continue to loop. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
<audio controls loop>
    <source src="Chiptronical.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  }
});
```

i wanted it to play the audio when the key is pressed but it just doesnt work

Comment: Please have a look at the Web Audio API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired results like this:-

Here is the html:-

```
<audio id="audioElement" controls loop>
    <source src="Chiptronical.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Here is the JavaScript:-

```
const audioElement = document.querySelector('#audioElement');
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      // For Play
      audioElement.play();
      // For Pause
      audioElement.pause();

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and run on browser. and press enter.
make sure directory is same with audio file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    
        $('body').append( `<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="Chiptronical.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="Chiptronical.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>` );
 }
});


    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>The audio autoplay attribute</h1>

<p>Press Enter to play a sound:</p>

</body>
</html>
```